# Scanning results from DB query that contain a % character

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm reading data from a `postgreSQL` DB in my GO code, which works smoothly until I try to `scan` column values of type string containing the character `%`. The resulting scanned string will contain `%!(MISSING)` instead of the %.

For example, the string value `this is a % test` becomes `this is a %!t(MISSING)est` after being scanned.

I'm using the regular lib/pq driver for go, using `database.Query(...).Scan(...)` methods.

**EDIT**: To clarify exactly what I'm doing and how I'm doing it.

I have a function that accepts an HTTP GET request:

```
func GetItems(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Setting header content type to json
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Calling another function that gets the items from postgres
    // and returns them as []structs
    items := pg.SelectItems(Database)

    // Marshall the []struct into a json byte array
    jsonItems, err := json.Marshal(items)

    // return the formatted response
    // I think that's where the problem is happening
    w.WriteHeader(200)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(response))
}
```

... and a function that does the querying and scans the results into GO structs:

```
func SelectItems (database *sql.DB) []Items {
    var result []Items
    queryStatement := `SELECT item_id,item_value FROM items`

    // Execute the DB Query
    rows, err := database.Query(queryStatement)

    // Loop over rows
    for rows.Next() {
        item := new(Item)
        // Scan values into item's fields
        err = rows.Scan(&item.ItemID, &item.ItemValue)

        if err != nil {
            // append the item to the array to be returned
            result = append(result, item)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

... where Items is defined as such:

```
type Item struct {
    ItemID    string    `json:"item_id"`
    ItemValue string    `json:"item_value"`
}
```

**Note:** I know that it's best practice to always handle all the errors, and to be sure to call `defer rows.Close()` after the DB query.. and I do in my production code, but i omitted them from the question just for the sake of clarity and readability.

Comment: To improve your question, please add some of the actual lines of code that represent the problem.  I personally struggle to imagine the missing details.

Comment: @miltonb You're right. I added some real code to the question to make it clearer. Note that to test that code, you'll need an sql db running. In the code, the `Database` object is the connection to that db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably parsing the string using some kind of formatting and therefore the `%` is being considered as a special character:

```
a := "hi % 123\n"
fmt.Printf(a)
```

This outputs `hi %!\n(MISSING)`

```
a := "hi % 123\n"
fmt.Println(a)
```

This on the other hand outputs `hi % 123` as expected.

In the first case we are using a function that formats the string, and therefore considers the `%` a special character, if you want to format a string that contains this character, just escape it:

`strings.Replace(str, "%", "%%", -1)`:

```
str := "hi % 123\n"
str2 := strings.Replace(str, "%", "%%", -1)
fmt.Printf(str2)
```

Since we escaped the `%` this outputs `hi % 123`

This is probably not a problem with the `Scan` function, it's a problem of how you are choosing to display the scanned data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right the problem is not in the `Scan` function. It's in the formatting. I've added code to the question that shows where it's happening. Wouldn't doing a `strings.Replace` every time this handler get called (which is a lot) add a lot of overhead to my server?

Comment: Nevermind :D The solution was simple.
It works if we call `fmt.Fprint` instead of `fmt.Fprintf`

Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, you should not use that value from the database as the first parameter to printf. Instead, use a formatting string with `%v`, or just use print or println. E.g.:
fmt.Printf('%v', a)

There's no need to resort to escaping.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you needed to format the string in some specific way so that's why I suggested escaping the `%`, if you're going to use it as is `fmt.Fprint` is much better.

Answer (score 1):

use `fmt.Fprint` instead of `fmt.Fprintf`

Comment: Yup.. that was it